# How to throw/catch the inner exception from a task?

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have a simple method:

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    try {
        myService.Do();
    } catch (MyException ex) {}
}
```

I have a service that uses `HttpClient`, and I do:

```
public void Do()
{
   var response = client.GetAsync(url).Result; //Alas it's not async till now
}
```

And now I'm implementing a `DelegatingHandler` and I override `SendAsync`:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
        .ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(task =>
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                throw new MyException();
            }

            return response;
        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Everything works as expected until a `MyException` is thrown here. The exception bubbles up to the caller, however, the exception is an `AggregrateException`.

Is there a way to throw the actual exception itself so that no major application-wide code-change is required?

Comment: I think this is due to the `ContinueWith`. Just move that code outside and after the `await`. Mixing `await` and `ContinueWith` is an odd thing to do, everything after the `await` *is* the continuation. It may also perhaps be due to calling `.Result` since you're no longer relying on async state machine to *unwrap* the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When exception is thrown in task then using `Result` property you will get `AggregateException` where the real exception is in `InnerException` property of this `AggregateException` object (your exception is wrapped by `AggregateException`).

To get the true exception (unwrapped exception) you can use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`:

```
var result = taskThatThrowsException.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

You can also use `Result` property but then you should specify some condition for exception handling;

```
try
{
    var result = taskThatThrowsException.Result;
}
catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is MyException myException)
{
    // use myException - it is your true unwrapped exception
}
```

But **you should NOT block asynchronous code** - you should asynchronously wait - use `await` and you will get your true unwrapped exception also:

```
var result = await taskThatThrowsException;
```

Answer (score 0):

`AggregrateException` is a consolidation of many exceptions, as an `async` method can throw many exceptions uppon its execution .net uses this class to return all of them.

To access the inner exceptions it has a property called `InnerExceptions`, it's a readonly collection that contains all the thrown ones.